# getorgchart: Disable double click and search event

Tags: getorgchart

I'm searching for a component in order to add to our website that allows to us to do some specific things.
[getOrgChart](http://www.getorgchart.com/) does all what we are looking for, but I have two questions.

1. It is possible to get the highlighted node after doing a search?
2. Can I disable the double click zoom feature?

I've been trying to search for any workaround using d3 framework with no result. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: This application doesn't look like something a developer would use.  Unless you're talking about interfacing with its API (in which case you need to be very explicit), this question's off-topic.

Comment: The behaviour that the component has is exactly what we are looking. for. The problem is that we don't want to zoom when a node is double clicked, because we use double click in other parts of our application and this feature reacts to other sides of the app. The second thing, using the api i have a diferent layout for the selected node, mapping onclickevent. But when i use the search component i whould like to apply the same layout to the found node.